# Deserialization fails with when using null as map key

Tags: java

Gson deserialization failed when using null  as map key

```
 Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                    .serializeNulls()
                    .serializeSpecialFloatingPointValues()
                    .create();
            Map<Integer, String> mapData = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
            mapData.put(null, "abc");
            String data = gson.toJson(mapData);

            System.out.println(data);
            Type type = TypeToken.getParameterized(HashMap.class, Integer.class, String.class).getType();

            Object obj = gson.fromJson(data, type);
            System.out.println(obj);
```

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "null"
```

The following code snippet work well.

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .serializeNulls()
                .serializeSpecialFloatingPointValues()
                .create();
        Map<String, Integer> mapData = new HashMap<>();
        mapData.put("abc", null);
        String data = gson.toJson(mapData);

        System.out.println(data);
        Type type = TypeToken.getParameterized(HashMap.class, String.class, Integer.class).getType();

        Object obj = gson.fromJson(data, type);
        System.out.println(obj);
```

output:

```
{"abc":null}
{abc=null}
```

Comment: null number primitives ... what do you mean by that?

Comment: Also please explain what *fails* means, do you get an exception? -> Put the exception into your question.

Comment: so, basically, you have a string "null" and you try to parse it to a numeric value. The problem seems quite clear

Comment: Nullable wrapper types don't exist in JSON, it only knows numbers, strings and booleans as "primitives", so gson can't convert `null` to a number

Comment: but map value can be null

Comment: You can use String and not Integer in your TypeToken. Then handle the different case (using if statements) to convert to Integer if possible. Or you can, change your map to not use null as a key

Comment: I want to know why it is wrong, instead of looking for other solutions@vincrichaud

Answer (score 1):

You can create [TypeAdapter](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/TypeAdapter.html) for `Integer`:

```java
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .serializeNulls()
        .serializeSpecialFloatingPointValues()
        .registerTypeAdapter(Integer.class, new TypeAdapter<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public void write(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Integer integer) throws IOException {
                jsonWriter.jsonValue(String.valueOf(integer));
            }
            @Override
            public Integer read(JsonReader jsonReader) throws IOException {
                if (jsonReader.peek() == JsonToken.NULL) {
                    jsonReader.nextNull();
                    return null;
                } else {
                    String numberStr = jsonReader.nextString();
                    return "null".equals(numberStr) ? null : Integer.valueOf(numberStr);
                }
            }
        })
        .create();
```

Output:

```
{"null":"abc"}
{null=abc}
```

The reason why `null` works for value and doesn't works for key without custom Integer Adapter, is the way map adapter serialises each: **key all the time is `String` in JSON, it couldn't be neither `int` or `null`**. You can see it in your output: `{"null":"abc"}` vs `{"abc":null}`.

Check out implementation of [map type adapter](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/internal/bind/MapTypeAdapterFactory.java#L238).